# Published app not automatically updating on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an app that was unpublished on the App Store `removed by developer`.

I have recently updated this app and updated the build. I have republished the app and it is green and `ready for sale`.

I am looking at my Ipad with the old app installed, it hasn't been updated.

How can I get the installed app to update automatically? So old users of the app can get the updated version.

Comment: do you have installed the new application from the AppStore?

Comment: with same version, i don't think apple notify to user.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the settings of the users, please check out the official docs: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202180

> With iOS 13 and iPadOS 13, apps and games that you download from the App Store are automatically updated by default. You won't see notifications about updating your apps. But you can also update apps manually. For example, if you want to force an update, you can update an [app manually](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202180#manual).

Updates itself can take up to 48hrs (or in some instances even a couple of days) to propagate to the App Store. Then you are at the mercy of the App Store app, when/if it updates apps.